# HDF5 integration with ROOT framework

Tags: hdf5, root-framework

I've worked extensively with [ROOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT), which has it's own format for data files, but for various reasons we would like to switch to [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) files. Unfortunately we'd still require some way of translating files between formats. Does anyone know of any existing libraries which do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might check out rootpy, which has a facility for converting ROOT files into HDF5 via PyTables:  http://www.rootpy.org/commands/root2hdf5.html

Comment: also found this independently (and it's all I've found).

Comment: There are now a few others: 
- https://github.com/havoc-io/root2hdf5
- https://github.com/diana-hep/rootconverter/blob/master/root2hdf5/src/root2hdf5.cpp

Answer (score 2):

If this issue is still of interest to you, recently there have been large improvements to [rootpy](https://github.com/rootpy/rootpy)'s [root2hdf5](http://www.rootpy.org/commands/root2hdf5.html) script and the [root_numpy](https://github.com/rootpy/root_numpy) package (which root2hdf5 uses to convert TTrees into NumPy structured arrays):

```
root2hdf5 -h
usage: root2hdf5 [-h] [-n ENTRIES] [-f] [--ext EXT] [-c {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}]
                 [-l {zlib,lzo,bzip2,blosc}] [--script SCRIPT] [-q]
                 files [files ...]

positional arguments:
  files

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n ENTRIES, --entries ENTRIES
                        number of entries to read at once (default: 100000.0)
  -f, --force           overwrite existing output files (default: False)
  --ext EXT             output file extension (default: h5)
  -c {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, --complevel {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
                        compression level (default: 5)
  -l {zlib,lzo,bzip2,blosc}, --complib {zlib,lzo,bzip2,blosc}
                        compression algorithm (default: zlib)
  --script SCRIPT       Python script containing a function with the same name 
                        that will be called on each tree and must return a tree or 
                        list of trees that will be converted instead of the 
                        original tree (default: None)
  -q, --quiet           suppress all warnings (default: False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of when I last checked (a few months ago) root2hdf5 had a limitation that it could not handle TBranches which were arrays.  For this reason I wrote a bash script: [root2hdf](https://github.com/ghollisjr/root2hdf) (sorry for non-creative name).

It takes a ROOT file and the path to the TTree in the file as input arguments and generates source code & compiles to an executable which can be run on ROOT files, converting them into HDF5 datasets.

It also has a limitation that it cannot handle compound TBranch types, but I don't know that root2hdf5 does either.

Comment: I got distracted by your `TH3Danim`. That's cool, but [it leaks memory](https://github.com/ghollisjr/TH3Danim/blob/master/TH3Danim.hh#L62).

Comment: Ah yes TH3Danim is a little dusty; I had really only used it inside of a ROOT session so it didn't complain about trying to free the memory on the first usage.  I'll patch it up.

Comment: pretty sure that still doesn't do it: you're calling the array destructor on an array of pointers, which will just delete all the pointers to the objects, without touching the objects.

Comment: then again, maybe I'm wrong... I don't know who actually owns the histograms that come out of `Project3D`, I suppose they may be owned by the "current directory". Anyway, it's this type of confusion that led me us away from ROOT in the first place.

Comment: Ugh yes you are right; now I must compulsively fix the code.  I ended up leaving ROOT as well; the cl-ana project is my attempt at using LISP, GSL, gnuplot and HDF5 to do data analysis instead of ROOT & c++.